# XMLRPC in Bugzilla 2.x

Tags: xml-rpc, bugzilla

I had a requirement to automate bug logging in Bugzilla. I googled and was able to make use of XML RPC in bugzilla.

But I couldn't make use of XML RPC in the bugzilla local server which was maintained by our Software Support Team. I am using Bugzilla version 2.20.2. Does this support XML RPC ??

I am able to communicate with another server of Bugzilla which is 3.6.2 .

How can we enable XMLRPC in the Bugzilla Installation ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if we use the installer available from [here](http://landfill.bugzilla.org/win32installer/) , and had installed the required perl modules it is working fine

Comment: above link does not exist

Comment: @RCBian The changes made in landfill maintenance makes the URL depricated.Will post new one , if I was able to get